# Offloading processing to a remote server in a game engine?

Tags: cloud-computing

What kinds of processes can you offload to a remote server in a game engine?

I'm thinking of making a real time multiplayer RTS, like Starcraft for example.

I was trying to offload as many processes as possible onto a remote server to:

1) Practice the techniques involved in order to offer a responsive gaming experience 
     while taking advantage of the latest cloud processing techniques.

2) To make an engine that's the most platform independent possible.

I've already thought of a couple of things that could be processed remotely:

1. AI (Path finding)
2. Volumetric particle effects (Smoke after an explosion)
3. Loading between levels?

I'm also most curious about the following things being possible:

1. Rendering
2. Physics

If anybody has any knowledge to share about this subject I'd very much appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is latency.

at 30fps, you get 33ms to do all of your *work*. Its highly unlikely that you'll have to time to farm things off to a remote server, and get things back within a frame boundary.
And thats before you deal with unstable network conditions, overloaded servers, network dropouts, etc etc.

Basically anything that needs to update within that frame boundary will be out. AI, physics, even particle effects.

Path finding you could potentially do off-client. But that also implies that you can farm off the entire local state of the game at the time to do it. It's going to be far easier and more performant to do it locally, even if you do it over the course of multiple frames locally. Which is a good point to bring up. You can always process things over multiple frames on the local CPU. Tasks like pathfinding are often done this way.

The problem will always be latency, and the time it takes to transfer enough of your local state somewhere else to be able to get them to do calculations for you. Doing it locally over the course of multiple frames offsets the second problem.

You could conceivably do theses kinds of tasks on a "server" of a client / server architecture to mitigate the "state" problem as much as possible, but this will put additional load on your C/S system (and usually the idea is that your "server" is very lightweight so you can run a hell of a lot of them on a single box). And you'll still suffer latency issues.

Comment: And that, my friends, is why the Xbox One's Azure cloud processing system is probably not going to be all that impressive.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* offload anything.  You *shouldn't* try to offload certain things if you want a smooth game.  For instance, physics is generally run on *both* the client and server in order for the client to predict where objects will move to compensate for the lag between the server's simulation state reaching the service.  Likewise with graphics.  Certainly the rise in streaming video games has shown that you can still get away with such processing on the server; you could just stream your game if that's what you're looking for.  Loading between levels *must* be on the client assuming the client needs to load something almost by definition.

However, I consider offloading to the client as a step *up* from cloud computing.  If the idea of the cloud is to have scalable elastic computing power then being able to "tap into" the computing power of your players is what the cloud was before "cloud" was even a buzzword.

Being portable doesn't necessitate offloading code to a server.  It just means writing portable code.  These days, you can compile C++ into standards-compliant JavaScript, with WebGL and other services across multiple browsers.  Game engines like Unity target a wide variety of platforms.  You can be quite widely portable without paying a bazillion in server costs.

Also don't forget that users tend to reject online-only games that aren't inherently online games.  See the outcry on Sim City or before that Assassin's Creed or so on.  If you're making an online game where the game has no value without being connected in itself, that's one thing, but if you're making a single-player experience you *really* don't want to make a server required to play.